# Сортировка элементов диагоналей вещественной прямоугольной матрицы, параллельных главной диагонали

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Столкнулся с такой задачей:
Напишите программу, которая считывает из файла матрицу, элементами
которой являются вещественные числа и сортирует элементы диагоналей вещественной
матрицы, параллельных главной диагонали, по не возрастанию:
А) сортировкой выбором; В) сортировкой вставками.

Все бы хорошо, но возникла огромная проблема с сортировками в прямоугольной матрице. Та сортировка, которая указана в программе, работает для квадратной матрицы. Переискал все источники - не нашел.

```
//Сортирует выбором и вставками элементы диагоналей матрицы,
//которые параллельны главным диагоналям по не возрастанию. 
//Элементы матрицы - вещественные числа. 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning ( disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

void ru_lang() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
}

class sort {
private:
int l, w;
float tmp;
public:
float** fill_matrix(char* name, int& n, int& m) {
    string input = name;
    ifstream file(input);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Файл не открывается." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    file >> n;
    file >> m;
    w = n;
    l = m;
    float **matrix = new float*[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new float[w];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            file >> matrix[i][j];
            //cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; //Проверка на тот случай, если не работает вывод матрицы
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return matrix;
}
void show_matrix(float** matrix) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Длина матрицы: " << w << endl;
    cout << "Ширина матрицы: " << l << endl << endl;
    cout << "Матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
/*void selection_sort(int** matrix) { //Сортировка выбором
    int i, j, tmp, m1, y;
    for (i = 1; i < m - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n && j + i < m; j++)
        {
            m1 = j;
            for (y = j + 1; y < n && y + i < m; y++)
                if (a[m1][i + m1] < a[y][y + i])
                    m1 = y;
            tmp = a[j][i + j];
            a[j][i + j] = a[m1][i + m1];
            a[m1][i + m1] = tmp;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n && j + i < m; j++)
        {
            m1 = j;
            for (y = j + 1; y < n && y + i < m; y++)
                if (a[m1 + i][m1] > a[y + i][y])
                    m1 = y;
            tmp = a[j + i][j];
            a[j + i][j] = a[m1 + i][m1];
            a[m1 + i][m1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}*/
float insertion_sort(float** matrix) {
    int i, j, m1, y;
    for (i = 1; i < l - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < w && j + i < l; j++)
        {
            m1 = j;
            for (y = j + 1; y < w && y + i < l; y++)
                if (matrix[m1][i + m1] < matrix[y][y + i])
                    m1 = y;
            tmp = matrix[j][i + j];
            matrix[j][i + j] = matrix[m1][i + m1];
            matrix[m1][i + m1] = tmp;
        }
    }
    /*for (i = 1; i < l - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < l && j + i < w; j++)
        {
            m1 = j;
            for (y = j + 1; y < l && y + i < w; y++)
                if (matrix[m1 + i][m1] > matrix[y + i][y])
                    m1 = y;
            tmp = matrix[j + i][j];
            matrix[j + i][j] = matrix[m1 + i][m1];
            matrix[m1 + i][m1] = tmp;
        }
    }*/
    return **matrix;
}
};

int main() {
ru_lang();
char name[80];
float** matrix;
int len, wd;
class sort Go;

cout << "Добро пожаловать в нашу программу!" << endl;
cout << "Введите название файла: (Как вводить: *название*.txt) (Пример: matrix.txt)" << endl;
cin >> name;
matrix = Go.fill_matrix(name, len, wd); //(1) Чтение из файла
Go.show_matrix(matrix); //(2) Вывод матрицы на консоль
//Go.selection_sort(); //(3) Сортировка выбором (первый метод)
Go.show_matrix(matrix); //(4) Вывод матрицы на консоль
//matrix = Go.fill_matrix(name, len, wd); //(5) Чтение из файла
Go.show_matrix(matrix);
Go.insertion_sort(matrix); //(7) Сортировка вставки (второй метод)
Go.show_matrix(matrix);
system("pause");
}
```

Это вводные данные:

```
matrix.txt
4 3
1 -9 2 3
2 3 4 5 
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Вообще-то надо решать, а не искать.

Comment: 1. Ваш класс не выражает осмысленную сущность. 2. В одной из функции я вижу обьект типа std::string. Хоть он и лишный, но от этого можно допускать, что вы можете применять и контейнеры из STL. В таком случаи, преставляйте матрицу в виде вектора векторов или std::valarray, тем более что после вызова первой же функции у вас утечка памяти, не говоря о других ошибках и о плохом подходе